# 96 tahoe with bad gas smell and trouble starting after warms up

Tags: starting, chevrolet, tahoe

I have a 96 tahoe we just changed the distributor thinking it was the cause but we still have a bad gas smell when starting and have trouble cranking after its warmed up. When you first start it for the day it starts no prob but after it warms up have to crank it multiple times to start it. My dad said it sounds out of time but the timing has been checked several times and its good. Any ideas?

Comment: Fuel smell indicates a fuel leak somewhere. My guess is leaky fuel distribution spider under intake manifold. $$$$. How many miles on odometer?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: 235000 on odometer

Answer (score 0):

Central Port Fuel Injection Spider leaking . It’s under the intake manifold, looks like it would be a tough job but I just replaced mine on a 97 Tahoe  it not as bad as it looks . It’s also a good time to clean your Throttle Body while you have it off.
For the part look on line at MotorMan.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).